# Regex to disallow two characters in a row

Tags: php, regex

I'm trying to modify this regex pattern so that it disallows two specified characters in a row or at the start/end -

```
/^[^\!\"\£\$\%\^\&\*\(\)\[\]\{\}\@\~\#\/\>\<\\\*]+$/
```

So at the moment it prevents these characters anywhere in the string, but I also want to stop the following from happening with these characters:

- any spaces, apostophes `'`, underscores `_` or hyphens `-` or dots `.` appearing at the start of end of the string
- also prevent any two of these characters in a row, i.e. `''` or `_._` or `' -__- ' .`

Any help would be hugely appreciated.

Thanks a lot

Comment: Do you want to repair, replace and carry on .. or on finding a fault, just abort?

Comment: Find fault and go boom :) thanks Cups

Comment: About this sentence: *also prevent any two of these characters in a row, i.e. '' or _._ or ' -__- ' .* OK so no single apostrophs in a row but what do you mean with the rest (`_._` and `' -__- ' .`)

Comment: Any of those characters one after another should fail, so you can't have two apostrophes, or two spaces, or a space and then an apostrophe, or a hyphen and a space, for example.

Comment: Ah. Just a thought: this looks like a pretty hairy solution. And if anyone comes up with a regex it's gonna be a nightmare to deal with I reckon. I think it's easier to *whitelist* characters rather than blacklist them. Let's say your starting point is "only letters and spaces.", then you might add hyphens, underscores and dots perhaps. With that knowledge you can for example say: The name must start with a letter and include at least 3 letters. Then you'd rule out most bogus names and can add further checks like no symbols in a row etc

Comment: If only I could, but then I would be listing pretty much the entire alphabet plus latin characters into the whitelist and that wouldn't really resolve the problem or having two in a row...

Comment: You can use the [\w escape sequence](http://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.escape.php) to match all "word" characters. This includes letters, digits and underscores. This will also match locale specific characters (ascii>128) if the appropriate locale is set. If you don't like that it includes digits it should be trivial to disallow the regex match if it contains any digits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way

```
/^(?=[^!"£$%^&*()[\]{}@~#\/><\\*]+$)(?!.*[ '_.-]{2})[^ '_.-].*[^ '_.-]$/
```

Note, only tested as javascript regex, i.e.

```
var rex = /^(?=[^!"£$%^&*()[\]{}@~#\/><\\*]+$)(?!.*[ '_.-]{2})[^ '_.-].*[^ '_.-]$/;
rex.test('okay');        // true
rex.test('_not okay');   // false
```

Or, to match on disallowed patterns

```
/^[ '_.-]|[ '_.-]$|[!"£$%^&*()[\]{}@~#\/><\\*]|[ '_.-]{2}/
```

The first regex will only match strings that contain no disallowed patterns.
The one above will match any disallowed patterns in a string.

*Update*

Now tested briefly using php. The only difference is that the `"` in the character set needed to be escaped.

```
<?php
$test = 'some string';
$regex = "/^[ '_.-]|[ '_.-]$|[!\"£$%^&*()[\]{}@~#\/><\\*]|[ '_.-]{2}/";
if ( preg_match( $regex, $test ) ) {
    echo 'Disallowed!';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand the exact problem, but here's a suggestion:

```
<?php
$test     = "__-Remove '' _._ or -__- but not foo bar '. _  \n";
$expected = 'Remove or but not foo bar';

// The list of disallowed characters. There is no need to escape.
// This will be done with the function preg_quote.
$excluded_of_bounds = "'_.-";

// Remove disallowed characters from start/end of the string.
// We add the space characters that should not be in the regexp.
$test = trim($test, $excluded_of_bounds . " \r\n");

// In two passes
$patterns = array(
  // 1/ We remove all successive disallowed characters,
  //    excepted for the spaces
  '#[' . preg_quote($excluded_of_bounds) . ']{2,}#',
  // 2/ We replace the successive spaces by a unique space.
  '#\s{2,}#',
);
$remplacements = array('', ' ');

// Go!
$test = preg_replace($patterns, $remplacements, $test);

// bool(true)
var_dump($expected === $test);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$tests[1]     = "fail_.fail";  // doubles
$tests[]     = "fail_-fail";
$tests[]     = "fail_ fail";
$tests[]     = "fail  fail";
$tests[]     = "fail -fail";
$tests[]     = "pas.s_1";
$tests[]     = "pa.s-s_2"; // singles
$tests[]     = "pas.s_3";
$tests[]     = "p.a.s.s_4";
$tests[10]     = "pa s-s_5";
$tests[]     = "fail fail'"; // pre or post-pended
$tests[]     = " fail fail";
$tests[]     = " fail fail";
$tests[]     = "fail fail_";
$tests[15]     = "fail fail-";

// The list of disallowed characters. There is no need to escape.
// This will be done with the function preg_quote.
$exclude = array(" ","'", "_", ".", "-");

$pattern =  "#[" . preg_quote(join("", $exclude)) . "]{2,}#s";

// run through the simple test cases 

foreach($tests as $k=>$test){
if( 
    in_array(substr($test, 0, 1), $exclude)  
 || in_array(substr(strrev($test), 0 , 1) , $exclude))
   {
   echo "$k thats a fail" . PHP_EOL;
   continue;
   }

  $test = preg_match( $pattern,  $test);
    if($test === 1){
    echo "$k - thats a fail". PHP_EOL ;
    }else{
    echo "$k - thats a pass $test ". PHP_EOL ;
    }
}
```

Stealing hopelessly from other replies, I'd advocate using PHPs simple in_array to check the start and end of the string first and just fail early on discovering something bad.

If the test gets past that, then run a really simple regex.

Stick the lot into a function and return false on failure -- that would rm quite a few verbose lines I added -- you could even send in the exclusion array as a variable -- but it would seem rather a specific function so may be YAGNI

eg

```
if( badString($exclude_array, $input) ) // do stuff
```